# field format does not hold when uploading to .csv

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal report that is totaling the hours per jobcode/paycode for each employee. The field which is being totaled is defined in total seconds but the group total field is being defined with a display formula which is converting total seconds to total hours/min.  The output of the report shows correctly with the total hours/min. per paycode. However, when I export the report to a .CSV formula the total is displaying in total seconds.  I need that field to export to .CSV in hours/min. or the same way as it shows in Crystal output.

Comment: I'm not personally familiar with `crystal-reports`, but I'd venture to guess that it might be useful if you shared some example data, or maybe the macro you are using for the the `hours/job code or pay code` column, if there is one.

Comment: If you are using a display formula to change the format of the field then you are not actually changing the data itself. You will need to incorporate that change in a formula and use the formula in your detail section rather than the field from the database